# Eclpise and pyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Possible duplicate but i couldn't find one.
I've downloaded python and am having trouble loading it into eclipse,
has anyone got a fool proof ground up solution that is garaunteed to work.
This is what i've tried,

Window--preferences--new--specified(Python 32) and C:\
 directory file to python.exe but it keeps spitting out invalid interpreter.

Comment: you might want to try aptana studio  3.  Its basically eclipse + pydev already set up for you.

Comment: but aptana costs moeny, doesn't it?

Comment: which version of eclipse and pydev are you trying to use?

Comment: [Check this](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/08/31/getting-started-using-python-eclipse/)

Comment: might be worth adding the [pydev] tag to your post... PyDev uses Stack Overflow as the support channel in lieu of a mailing list or forum, and the lead developer can probably help you out.

Comment: Just to note, Aptana is free (and open source).

Answer (score 0):

As they say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567895/eclipse-pydev-installation-difficulties?rq=1) uninstall, delete the .metadata folder and install again.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is that you're probably pointing to a shortcut and not the actual executable, so, can you check if you're really giving the executable (and not a shortcut) in the interpreter configuration process?

If that's not the case, please post details you may have in your error log during that process.